# Can't find where the preview window is in Android Studio 4.0(Canary)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-4.0

I'm going through the tutorials about Jetpack which is ran in the Android Studio 4.0(Canary), please refer to the link post below.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

Everything is ready except I can't find the preview window since I try to preview the "Composable" method.

Can someone give me an exact hint that where the preview window is?

Comment: do you have a method with the @Preview annotation on it?

Comment: @Blundell yeah sure I have a method like that, I just can't find an entrance to open the preview window.

Comment: after I restarted Android Studio it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build the project first (Build -> Make Project). I also had to restart Android Studio in order for previews to start working.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [official site](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial#preview-your-function-in-android-studio):

> Beginning with Android Studio 4.0 Canary 1, Android Studio lets you preview your composable functions within the IDE, instead of needing to download the app to an Android device or emulator. The main restriction is, the composable function must not take any parameters. **Add the `@Preview` annotation before `@Composable`.**

Then select on the top-right the **Editor and Preview** toggle.

[image]

[image]

To update the preview click the **Build Refresh** button.

[image]

Comment: Hi, The question was that  I've followed the guide of official site and I can find nothing on the top-right of my Android Studio, I get no entrance to open the preview window.

Comment: Ok, I take the advice from @Alex H and it just works after I restart Android Studio.

Comment: Is this behaviour by design (@Preview + restart AS) ? 
Anyway, have anyone filed an issue at issuetracker on this ?

Comment: @RoarGrønmo The preview works if the project can be built. If there are errors the preview doesn't work. It doesn't need a restart in my experience.

Comment: As a principle, the preview should rather be showing an errormessage / lint when trying to show the preview, rather than not showing anything at all. At once the @Preview annitation is used, the preview window should be brought up. -> We may suggest this at issuetracker.

Comment: Found this at issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143281991 I hope it will be adressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. Then realized i forgot to add these line in gradle

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}
```