# Android Studio 4.0 can not switch from design to text mode in xml

Tags: android-studio-4.0

Android Studio 4.0 can not switch from design to text mode in xml. I tried solution as overriding shortcut [Shortcut to switch between design and text in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682455/shortcut-to-switch-between-design-and-text-in-android-studio) but it does not help

Comment: Can you switch with the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can't find where the preview window is in Android Studio 4.0(Canary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621252/cant-find-where-the-preview-window-is-in-android-studio-4-0canary)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

To,

```
"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```